# Optimisation procedure in Scala (Brent's Method)

Tags: function, scala, statistics, solver

I'm trying to build a power analysis tool in Scala. In particular, I'm trying to create a function which does return the required sample size given some restrictions (statistical power, effect size, the ratio between the two sample sizes, significance level and the type of hypothesis test we would like to run).

I wrote the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.UnivariateFunction
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BrentSolver
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution
import scala.math._

object normal_sample_size extends App {

  val theta1 = 0.0025
  val theta2 = theta1 * 1.05
  val split = 0.50
  val power = 0.80
  val significance = 0.05
  val alternative = "two sided"

  val result = requiredSizeCalculationNormal(effectSizeCalculation(theta1, theta2), split, power, significance, alternative)
  println(result)

  def effectSizeCalculation(mu1: Double, mu2: Double): Double = {
    2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(mu1)) - 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(mu2))
  }

  def requiredSizeCalculationNormal(effect_size: Double, split_ratio: Double, power: Double, significance: Double, alternative: String): Unit = {

    if (alternative == "two sided") {

      val z_score = new NormalDistribution().inverseCumulativeProbability(significance / 2.0)
      val func = new UnivariateFunction {def value(n: Double) = (1 - new NormalDistribution().cumulativeProbability(z_score.abs - effect_size * sqrt(n * split_ratio * n * (1 - split_ratio)))) +
        new NormalDistribution().cumulativeProbability(z_score - effect_size * sqrt(n * split_ratio * n * (1 - split_ratio)))}
      val solver = new BrentSolver()
      try {solver.solve(500, func, 0.001, 1000000)} catch {case _:Throwable => None}

    } else if (alternative == "less") {

      //val z_score = new NormalDistribution().inverseCumulativeProbability(significance)
      //new NormalDistribution().cumulativeProbability(z_score - effect_size * sqrt(n * split_ratio * n * (1 - split_ratio)))

    } else if (alternative == "greater") {

      //val z_score = new NormalDistribution().inverseCumulativeProbability(significance).abs
      //1 - new NormalDistribution().cumulativeProbability(z_score - effect_size * sqrt(n * split_ratio * n * (1 - split_ratio)))

    } else {

      println("Error message: Specify the right alternative. Possible values are 'two sided', 'less', 'greater'")

    }
  }
}
```

`requiredSizeCalculationNormal()` recognises what type of hypothesis testing is dealing with ("two sided", "greater" or "less") and then computes the required sample size. This last point is where I'm struggling! Using Brent's Method (from math3 library) I would like to find the value of n which solve the function.

Going through the code, focusing only on the "two sided" part of my function (I'll complete "greater" and "less" in a second stage), I've tried to create a function named `func`. Then using the command `try {solver.solve(500, func, 0.001, 1000000)} catch {case _:Throwable => None}` I'm trying to solve it using max 500 iterations and within the interval (0.001, 1000000). Unfortunately the command doesn't return neither a result nor an error message.

EDIT: I've removed from the code quoted above the `//catch {case _:Throwable => None}` (None was redundant anyway). That piece of code was actually catching all exceptions and doing nothing with them. 
The exceptions I see running the code are:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NoBracketingException: function values at endpoints do not have different signs, endpoints: [2, 10,000,000], values: [0.05, 1]
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BrentSolver.doSolve(BrentSolver.java:118)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.solve(BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.solve(BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.java:195)
    at normal_sample_size$.requiredSizeCalculationNormal(normal_sample_size.scala:46)
    at normal_sample_size$.delayedEndpoint$normal_sample_size$1(normal_sample_size.scala:31)
    at normal_sample_size$delayedInit$body.apply(normal_sample_size.scala:22)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at normal_sample_size$.main(normal_sample_size.scala:22)
    at normal_sample_size.main(normal_sample_size.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So the problem seems to be that the function doesn't change sign within the specified interval.

Comment: tldr; are you asking how to use the Brent solver from commons math (possibly from Scala)? If so, you should remove all the other information that does not contribute to the question.

Comment: @ziggystar yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I've shortened the question, to go straight to the point.